# In python how do I compare an array/list to a number

Tags: python, arrays

```
array = []
while len(array) < 1000:
    i=2
if i%array == 0:
    append.array(i)
i = i + 1
print array[999]
```

For learning purposes I am trying to find the 1000th prime number. The only problem is I cannot find a way to check whether i is divisible by an element in the array.
    if i%array == 0:
is not the correct syntax so what is?

Comment: Also if there is an easier way to approach this problem please let me know!

Comment: actually the algorithm whic ur trying to do is wrong for primenumber

Comment: other thing is i%array given array is list how can u divide a number with list

Comment: What you stated was my question. i was trying to compare a number with a list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
any(item%i == 0 for item in array)
```

Basically, you check if any item of your generator expression satisfied your condition.

From [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all):

```
 all(iterable)

    Return True if all elements of the iterable are true (or if the iterable is empty).
```

I'm not familiar enough with Python to know how efficient it is though. To avoid having to test every item in your array, you could also try to filter how many times you test your condition. As an example, the following line would give you a list of all the elements up to the 1st that doesn't satisfy the condition. From that you can know both whether your condition was satisfied (by checking the length for example) and which item satisfied it.

```
filtered = list(itertools.takewhile(lambda item: item%a != 0, array))
if len(filtered) != len(array):
    print array[len(filtered)]
```

Here I've chosen to stop at the 1st element that satisfies the condition but there are probably other ways too!

Comment: It's a generator, not a list :P

Comment: @user3743825 My pleasure, don't forget to accept the answer for our fellow programmers of the future who may encounter the same problem

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly where the difference between lists and arrays comes in. In a list you can not check each value against another one, just as you can not simply divide each element by dividing the list:

```
>>> list=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
>>> list==5
False
>>> list/5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#18>", line 1, in <module>
    list/5
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'int'
```

Whereas with an array, you can do these things:

```
>>> from numpy import array
>>> array=array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
>>> array==5
array([False, False, False, False,  True, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
>>> any(array==5)
True
>>> any(array==50)
False
>>> array/5
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
array = []
while len(array) < 1000:
    i=2
if i%array == 0:
    append.array(i)
i = i + 1
print array[999]
```

You asked:

> if i%array == 0: is not the correct syntax so what is?

In your code, `array` is a list.  You cannot compute the modulus of an integer and a list; that makes no sense.  So Python gives you a `TypeError` exception.

Your code is very strange and confused.  I think you would do well to study an introduction to Python programming, such as *Learn Python the Hard Way* which is free online:

http://learnpythonthehardway.org/

To find a prime number, a good way is to use the Sieve of Eratosthenes.  The Rosetta Code wiki has sample code for this, with 11 different ways to solve it using Python.  I think the simplest one is the first one, using set lookup:

http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Using_set_lookup

But to answer your specific question, you can check to see whether a number is divisible by an element of the array using code like this:

```
# see whether the number n is divisible by the number at index 3 in array
if n % array[3]:
    print("True")
else:
    print("False")
```

EDIT: check whether a number is divisible by any of the elements inside an array.

```
def divisible_by_any(number, lst):
    for n in lst:
        if number % n == 0:
            return True
    return False
```

This uses modulus to check whether a number is evenly divisible by each number `n` from a list of numbers `lst`.  If any check succeeds, returns `True` immediately.  If every number is checked and the loop terminates, returns `False`.

There is a shorter way to do the above operation in Python, using a built-in function `any()`.

```
def divisible_by_any(number, lst):
    return any(number % n == 0 for n in lst)
```

The two are exactly equivalent, but the second one runs faster since it is using Python's built-in feature of the `any()` function.  This is an example of how learning all the cool stuff built in to Python can make your programs quicker to write, yet faster.

Comment: Thanks for the resource! It's very well written. Also my question was worded incorectly. I wanted to check whether a number was divisible by any of the elements held in array[].